# What camera is best for abstract photography?

Tags: camera-recommendation

What features do I need to look at in a dslr for my abstract photos? What will give me good color capture?

Comment: Abstract photography is a broad subject; you might want to share a sample image you have in mind.

Comment: I cant think of ANY reason hardware is a specific factor in "abstract photography" (which is itself very subjective) - It's what you point it at the matters.

Comment: You should probably be more specific about exactly what kind of subjects in what kind of lighting conditions you're thinking about. 'Abstract Photography' is a very broad and nebulous label that can mean many things to many people.

Answer (score 4):

Simple answer: unless you are very, very demanding in your requirements, *any* camera with a reasonably large sensor (say micro 4/3s or bigger) and the ability to shoot in RAW will do you just fine. Don't worry about brand or comparing colour depth on DxOMark or anything like that - modern digital cameras are all good; the differences are much more about form factor and personal like or dislike of the interface than technical differences between the sensor or even the lenses.

Just get out there and start shooting rather than worrying about gear.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting line of thought. The usual suspects - such as low light performance, color rendition, frames per second and so on - do not really apply in pure abstract photography.

The only constraint I can think of is that you will want to experiment with lens (it usually goes that the more the better). So Canon or Nikon, as these have the largest lens lineup. The exact model probably does not matter (so buy a cheap one).

If abstract photography is your game do give a thought to film also - long exposure pinhole images or photograms can look wonderfully abstract.

Comment: I don't think there is any particular reason to constrain yourself to Canon or Nikon. Pentax, Olympus/Panasonic, Sony, Fujifilm, and Sigma all have respectable lens lineups which cover a wide variety of experimentation. It's only if you're really looking for a particular specialty lens that you might make that your primary decision point.